# Celery rate limit requests

Tags: python, api, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue

I need to find a way to rate limit RabbitMQ delivery tasks my Internal API Server.

This is my flow:

**API client > Internal API > RabbitMQ > Celery (120 workers) > External API**

API client sends Web request to internal API, Internal API process the request and Task is sent to RabbitMQ. Task duration could take from 5 seconds to 120 seconds, there are situations in which tasks start to Queue up and they get sent to external API at a higher rate than the one defined, resulting in numerous failed requests. (Around 5% of failed requests)

[image]

Each request becomes a RabbitMQ task. RabbitMQ by default delivers the task as fast as it can, causing that tasks that are queued get delivered at a faster rate as soon as a worker is freed. (> 10 QPS),

**Question**: How to rate limit task delivery at RabbitMQ?

Versions:

- Flask
- RabbitMQ 3.6.4
- AMPQ 1.4.9
- kombu 3.0.35
- Celery 3.1.23
- Python 2.7

Possible solution:

- Increase External API limit externally...
- Add more workers
- Keep track of failed tasks and retry them later

Although those solutions may work, is not solving exactly the implementation of my rate limiter and controlling the real rate in which my workers can process the API requests.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just edited the question, looking to rate limit task delivery in RabbitMQ

Comment: would [`rate_limit`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit) help?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found any configuration examples nor documentation.

Comment: I found  CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER and -Ofair option in Celery.

Comment: @spicyramen have yo found a solution to this?